# How can I share from an android app to a kivy app

Tags: kivy

Is it possible to share a string to a kivy app on an android phone? For example: Can I mark a word in a browser, click on "Share to", choose my kivy app, and thus the word is pasted in a label in my kivy app?

Comment: You can probably achieve this using Android's intents, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Comment: Does just copy-pasting not suit your needs? It seems good enough for a string. I'd be interested to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but not nice: three more clicks.